# How to correctly label call_user_func to prevent warning : Exception is never thrown in the corresponding 'try' block (PhpStorm / Lumen)?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, lumen

I have Authenticate middleware in my Lumen app that looks like this:

```
class Authenticate
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string|null $guard = null): mixed
    {
        try {
            /** @var \Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard $requestGuard */
            $requestGuard = $this->auth->guard($guard);
            $signedIn = $requestGuard->check();

            // ...

        } catch (NoUserIdProvidedException) {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

It works fine, but PhpStorm reports that the exceptions (I removed most from the example, there are a few) are not thrown by the containing block, when they are.

Seems that deep in the RequestGuard it uses call_user_func

```
return $this->user = call_user_func(
    $this->callback, $this->request, $this->getProvider()
);
```

To call a closure set up in the AuthServiceProvider, which uses the middleware method on the custom Security class:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            $security = new Security();

            return $security->middleware($request);
        });
    }
}
```

The middleware looks to me docblocked correctly

```
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return bool|object|null
     * @throws InvalidDomainUser
     * @throws NoDomainUserException
     * @throws NoTokenOnRecordException
     * @throws NoTokenProvidedException
     * @throws NoUserException
     * @throws NoUserIdProvidedException
     */
    public function middleware(Request $request): object|bool|null
    {
```

adding the docblocks, like:

```
/**
* @throws NoUserIdProvidedException
*/
```

in the closure, the auth provider or the handle code does not make the warning go away, is there a way to comment or type hint the code to avoid false positives? I don't want to just switch off the inspection.

Comment: Seems like your hint is not valid doc-block, as it starts with /*, not /**. Please try to fix this and check what happens.

Comment: Which line/method in your first code sample supposed to throw that exception? Does that method has the needed `@throws` lines in their doc block? If it's somewhere deep inside then I do not think that PhpStorm can guess/handle this. BTW -- what do you have for "Settings/Preferences | PHP", Analysis tab, "Call tree analysis depth". Maybe higher value than default `1` can do better here.

Comment: thanks @IliaYatsenko, looks to be just a typo in my question rather than the code, have updated the Q.

Comment: @LazyOne the $requestGuard->check() calls the code that throws the exceptions, the code that throws is mine, but the RequestGuard is part of lumen/laravel so don't want to hack the Framework. Increasing the call tree does not fix the issue

Comment: @CodeMonkey So the exception is expected in `$requestGuard->check()` call (that calls some method in "fancy" way). Is it annotated as "I can throw such an exception" tags? As I understand not. If that's the case then the IDE cannot do much here. I may only suggest to either ignore or suppress the warning via inline comment (`Alt+Enter` on the issue, find the most appropriate inspection, `right arrow` to expand the submenu and select the right item there).

Comment: @LazyOne - shame that the code is too fancy for static analysis, especially with Laravel / Lumen being so commonplace. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Make your own answer -- you can better describe what you have managed to get and not (why not).

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks, my first thought was to share the internet points, but looks like you're doing just fine lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the way the guards work is just a bit too convoluted for static analysis, so I refactored, moving the underlying custom code out of the guard, and directly into the middleware and this worked, the exceptions are now correctly detected.

```
class Authenticate
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string|null $guard = null): mixed
    {
        try {
            $security = new Security();
            $user = $security->middleware($request);
            $signedIn = !empty($user->id);

            // ...

        } catch (NoUserIdProvidedException) {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

The security class is custom logic, the important bit is that the doc blocks with the @throws are close enough to be found by the IDE

```
class Security{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return bool|object|null
     * @throws InvalidDomainUser
     * @throws NoDomainUserException
     * @throws NoTokenOnRecordException
     * @throws NoTokenProvidedException
     * @throws NoUserException
     * @throws NoUserIdProvidedException
     */
    public function middleware(Request $request): object|bool|null
    {
      // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a very satisfying conclusion, if you have anything better, please post an answer